# Fischer Esterification of the Unsaturated 3-Butenoic Acid with Methyl Alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am attempting to perform a Fisher esterification of 3-butenoic acid (vinyl acetic acid). I believe that this should theoretically work and not disturb the unsaturated region of the molecule, but I'm not certain. Has anyone had any practical experience with this in the lab or seen any literature referencing a Fischer esterification being performed on an unsaturated acid? Theoretically, since the esterification is being performed with anhydrous methanol with a sulfuric acid catalyst the acid-catalyzed hydration should not be possible; however, as the reaction progresses, water present in the reaction mixture may hydrate the alkene. Will this not be an issue since there will still be a large excess of methanol or will I need to find a physical method to remove the water from the reaction as it forms? Given, a Dean-Stark apparatus cannot be used. I'm thinking about using molecular sieves to remove any trace of water as it forms in situ but I don't know if this would work? Has anyone ever attempted this or something similar?

Comment: You can add equivalents of methyl orthoformate or orthoacetate to remove water. The byproducts will be methyl formate or acetate, respectively. Distillation should be trivial.

Comment: Use BF3.MeOH complex as catalyst instead of Sulfuric

Comment: Are you asking us to perform your literature research for you?

Comment: I am just wondering if anyone has had any specific experience with this reaction in the lab, as I could not find any literature on this. I may have missed something in my literature review, so I just wanted to include that question in the case, but I'm mostly worried about practical advice, as I am relatively new to synthetic research.

Comment: I will edit my question, however, to be more specific

Comment: Be careful handling crotonic (butenoic) acid esters. They are vesicants. Alas, I speak from experience. By the way, Google Clinton-Laskowski method for the esterification of acids to methyl esters.